# How to trigger hover when hovering over another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger the hover css also when hovered over #boks2.

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u9byh/

My HTML:

```
<div id="boks1"></div>
<div id="boks2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#boks1 {width:50px;height:50px;background:blue;}
#boks1:hover {background:red;}
#boks2 {width:50px;height:50px;border:1px solid black;margin-top:10px;}
```

Jquery:

```
$(jQuery){
    $('#boks2').hover(function() {
        $('#boks1').hover();   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jordanbaucke/buyC9/3/

Answer (score 3):

You can't trigger the CSS `:hover` from jQuery. What you could do is to toggle a class on the other element. Like this:

#### CSS

```
#boks1 {width:50px;height:50px;background:blue;}
#boks1.onHover, #boks1:hover {background:red;}
#boks2 {width:50px;height:50px;border:1px solid black;margin-top:10px;}
```

#### jQuery

```
$(function() { //on dom ready handler fixed as Sarfraz pointed out
    $('#boks2').hover(function() {
       $('#boks1').toggleClass('onHover');   
    });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#boks2').hover(function() {
     $('#boks1').trigger('hover');   
});

$('#boks1').bind('hover',function(){
     $(this).css('background-color','red');
})
```

u can check here http://jsfiddle.net/Wc7MC/

Comment: We is it needed to write the CSS two times?